# Is it possible to create a file that acts as a hyperlink to a website?

Tags: filesystems, hyperlink, portable

I recently decided that my CV should be an HTML file, because it's very consistent (unlike .docx or .odf files which require reorganizing everything sometimes, when some object displaces some other).

I also realized that when I deliver my CV, I deliver a snapshot of it, and I would prefer it to receive updates (maybe I finish a new course after already having delivered my CV; or maybe I notice a typo the day after).

So when I deliver my CV to someone through email, I can send them the link to my website where my CV is hosted, which is fine.  But when some job offer requires you to drop a file, I'd like to be able to deliver a file that will be recognized as a hyperlink in any system (Linux, BSD (or OS X), Windows).

Is that possible?

I checked that when I create a link in Windows, I end up with a file like this:

`link.url`:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.example.com
```

and in Linux, I end up with a file like this:

`link.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Link
Name=CV
Comment=
Icon=user-bookmarks
URL=http://www.example.com
```

It's weird that if you rename a Linux link in the GUI (at least in XFCE), the actual file name isn't modified (`ls` keeps showing the old file name).

May I mix these so that each system uses the part it understands, or is there any portable format?

Comment: I have thought about the impression that causes delivering a hyperlink as the CV file, which may not be ideal, and it might be better to deliver an HTML file with a link to the latest version at the end, and I will continue wondering about what is the best solution for that. But the question is still valid for other uses, such as keeping a link to a website in a partition that both Linux and windows open.

Comment: Ummmmm, no. Most CVs are read by machines, and they won't like being forcibly redirected, even if you get such a thing to work. Second, forced links like this would be used by every virus maker around the globe if they were at all a thing, so they aren't. Third, there's already link files that do what you want, but there's a good reason (See points one and two above) why they aren't accepted by any real CV acceptance system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is a solution, that is universal across OSes.
If I understand correctly, all you need is a file that when clicked in any popular OS, will open a link to a particular webpage in the system's web browser.

For that just create a file with a `.html` extension with the following contents:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>filesystems - Is it possible to create a file that acts as a hyperlink to a website? - Super User</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" charset="utf-8" content="0; url=https://superuser.com/questions/1581651/is-it-possible-to-create-a-file-that-acts-as-a-hyperlink-to-a-website" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Loading 
       <a href="https://superuser.com/questions/1581651/is-it-possible-to-create-a-file-that-acts-as-a-hyperlink-to-a-website">filesystems - Is it possible to create a file that acts as a hyperlink to a website? - Super User</a>
    ...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is for a html file that when clicked will open the current Stack Exchange page.

The above code was generate by a [Firefox add-on](https://github.com/nbeaver/save_link_webextension) made for this exact purpose.

Comment: This will only work within a browser.

Comment: @Toto but being an HTML file, it is going to be very close to universal. Considering the request is for a URL to be opened, and the specific use case is for loading a website, this should work. Whether email hosts will allow a redirecting html file as an attachment is another question.

Comment: @music2myear: You're right but that doesn't really anwser the question.

Answer (score 3):

There is no universal link file type.

Existing mainstream file types for documents or information transfer will not support automated links because of the obvious security implications of such.

Most systems that require a file be uploaded use automated processes to "read" that file, and these won't work with a link. They require the given file types because these are the file types the system can read, and the types that are common for conveying document information.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most cross-platform way would be to deliver a html file. This would allow you to use -in a portable way- a number of tricks:

- You could embed your webpage in an <iframe> (it won't work if they open on a system without internet!)
- The html CV might contain a <meta refresh or javascript which switche to the online version
- The CV might have javascript that automatically showed a banner "This CV was current 3 months 5 days ago, you are encouraged to view the last version at https://CacahueteFrito.com/CV ".
- You could include web bugs.

While HR departments are generally not too tech-savvy, you should also take into account the image those would give if/when found. I wouldn't like discovering google analytics into the CV of a candidate. Some people may have problem viewing it if "the CV changes automatically". It could also be confusing if multiple people in the interview process actually saw different versions of your CV (user A printed the original html file, user B opened the webpage and got transparently redirected).

Needless to say, if you made a CV that depends on an url, whatever url you choose [must not change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI), it shall continue working in the future.